# What is the best way to query for a date saved in MongoDB with the format YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My current documents looks like this:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  nextBillingDate: '2018-02-12',
}
```

I need a way to query for documents that have a `nextBillingDate` ***less*** or ***equal*** to today.

For example, if I have the following documents:

```
[
  {
    _id: 123,
    nextBillingDate: '2018-02-12'
  },
  {
      _id: 789,
      nextBillingDate: '2018-02-01'
  },
  {
      _id: 654,
      nextBillingDate: '2018-02-28'
  }
]
```

And today is `2018-02-12`, the result of the query needs to contain the documents with the `_id` 123 and 789.

Comment: If you are opeen to changing DB schema, store them as ISODate

Comment: I don‘t know mongodb in detail, but what happens if you compare it by string? The `YYYY-MM-DD` format allows a string based comparison of dates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
db.col.find(
    {$expr : 
        {$lte : 
            [
                {$dateFromString : {dateString : "$nextBillingDate"}},
                new Date("2018-02-12")
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

using aggregation

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$match :
        {$expr : 
            {$lte : 
                [
                    {$dateFromString : {dateString : "$nextBillingDate"}},
                    new Date("2018-02-12")
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```